# How to redirect page and highlight some text on the new open page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a Frequently asked questions Page, when a user clicks the FAQ anchor i want the page to redirect to FAQ questions and highlight a word, then scroll and focus the screen on the highlighted word.

No Plugins Please.

Comment: Please post some code segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I got it. Try

```
<div class="faque_question_table">
  <ul>
        <li  id="q1"><a class="qli" href="answer.html?#ans1">Create new course</a></li>
        <li  id="q2"><a class="qli" href="answer.html?#ans2">Set privacy and assign users</a>/li>
         <li  id="q3"><a class="qli" href="answer.html?#ans3">View course.</a></li>
         <li  id="q4"><a class="qli" href="answer.html?#ans4">Edit and delete course.</a></li>
         <li  id="q5"><a class="qli" href="answer.html?#ans5">Add thumbnail representation.</a></li>
    </ul>

 </div>
<!-- After some code your answer.html-->
<div class="help_sub_content" id='ans1'>  Your answer 1</div>
 <div class="help_sub_content" id='ans2'>  Your answer 1</div>
<div class="help_sub_content" id='ans3'>  Your answer 1</div>
<div class="help_sub_content" id='ans4'>  Your answer 1</div>
```

Then **script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

          $(".qli").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top},1000) //Will maybe be $(window) instead of html,body.
    return false;
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Blessing you can choose your right answer. Anyway thanks for suggest an edit.

Comment: I like your answer. Let's fix two things though. 1. Page redirects and scrolls to the right place, but scrolls back up after some time. Probably the page hasnt finished loading, but i have the dom ready function. 2. Let's use classes instead of IDs so that the answer can be referenced across all pages. So how do you write this? 'answer.html?class'

Answer (score 1):

You could perform this so easily mate.Just try the following script,its quite useful.I have done a `fiddle` that suits your purpose.Since you need to go to the word once a link is clicked pass the `identifier word` with the url after a `# symbol` or something and obtain that word using a javascript `split`

Code

```
$('.disclosure').highlight('Test');
 $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(".highlight").offset().top
     }, 1500);
```

Include this script

http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-4.js

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HehgB/

Without any external plugins

```
var src_str = $(".disclosure").html();
var term = "massa";
term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "i");

src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
src_str = src_str.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");
$(".disclosure").html(src_str);
 $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("mark").offset().top
     }, 1500);
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4tZ55/

Comment: I would avoid any extra js as possible, all i want is the scroll and highlight without plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Put `id="some-id"` on the word's container and then put the ID on the URL:

```
http://example.com/faq#some-id
```

If you want some fancy scrolling to happen, and fade in the word, then you can use something like jQuery. There are quite a few plugins that do fancy scrolling. The fading can be done without using a plugin.